# Place a button and its div with one command

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently, I have a `button` class which lets me place a clickable button inside a sentence, and a `div` class which lets me add content to the button which I placed at the end of the paragraph containing the sentence.

This is an example of how I use them

```
Try to click <button class="col">THIS</button> and see what happens.
<div class="con">nice!</div>
Did you try?
```

When this text is displayed on the page, the two sentences are placed inside two different paragraphs, so the `div` object is placed between them.

Here is a snippet with the css classes and the javascript.

```js
( function() {
    coll = document.getElementsByClassName("col");
    conn = document.getElementsByClassName("con");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
        coll[i].setAttribute('data-id', 'con' + i);
        conn[i].setAttribute('id', 'con' + i);
        coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var content = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('data-id'));
            if (content.style.maxHeight) {
                content.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else {
                content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
            }
        });
    }
} )();
```

```css
.col {
  cursor: help;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: red;
}

.con {
  padding: 0 1em;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .3s ease;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
Try to click <button class="col">THIS</button> and see what happens.
<div class="con">nice!</div>
Did you try?
```

I wonder if it is possible to implement a shortcut to place the two objects with one command, that is to obtain the previous example by using something like this

```
Try to click [[THIS|nice!]] and see what happens.
Did you try?
```

What I mean is that the command `[[THIS|nice!]]` should place the object `<button class="col">THIS</button>` in the same position and the object `<div class="con">nice!</div>` at the end of the paragraph containing the command.

Is it possible to implement such a command (or a similar one)?

### EDIT

I forgot to say that the content of the button, ie what is written inside the div, should also be possible to be a wordpress shortcode, which is a shortcut/macro for a longer piece of code or text.

Comment: do you mean initially it would be `[[THIS|nice!]]` and then on click gets replaced by a button and div?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you mean, What i was thinking about is that in the text editor I write `Try to click [[THIS|nice!]] and see what happens.` but then when the page is displayed, what it is shown is exactly what you see when you run the code snippet. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery, `closest()` find the nearest `<p>` element and add `<div class="con">nice!</div>` after `<p>` element. To toggle you can use class `active` and add or remove `.con` element.

```js
$('.col').click(function(){
    let traget = $(this).closest('p');
    if(traget.hasClass('active')) {
       traget.removeClass('active');
       traget.next('.con').remove();
    } else {
       traget.addClass('active');
       traget.after(`<div class="con">${$(this).data('message')}</div>`);   
    } 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Try to click <button class="col" data-message="Hello">THIS</button> and see what happens.</p>
<p>Did you try?</p>
```

Comment: thanks this is a starting point, problem is that is not possibile to close the button

Comment: @soundwave you can use class to toggle .con element.

Comment: thanks for correction, is there a way to set the content of the div class from the html code? `nice!` is just an example, but when i use the button, the content is not always the same

Comment: @soundwave you can use data attrbute to embed custom data

Comment: thank you very much this is very good! i forgot to say that the content of the button should also be possibile to be a shortcode (which is a shortcut/macro used in wordpress) but if i put a shortcode in the `data-message`, then when i click on the button it just shows the shortcode name, not its content. i think this is the limit of the this approach, i will ask on wordpress forum. thanks again

Comment: @soundwave if this answer did solve your issue, please do mark it as the correct answer. It will be helpful for future users as well as rewarding for the person who took effort to help solve your issue.

Comment: @Gosi I'd like to read some other approaches, maybe somebody knows how to solve the problem about shortcodes. Moreover, maybe somebody knows if it is possibile to implement a code like `[[button name|button content]]` which is more clean. I will wait few days.

Answer (score 0):

You usually dont use div to type text. you use it to define areas or group items. you could obtain what youre asking for in a 1 sentence like this:

**html**

```
<h1> some random text <a class="btnID">button</> some more text<h1>
```

**css**

```
   .btnID {
    color: red;
    }
```

Comment: did you run my snippet?